# Using rails link_to with just an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page that needs a link to a User page with a given ID. So if the ID is 1234, I want the final href to be /user/1234.

I tried to use

```
link_to "User", {:controller => "user", :action => "show", :id => 1234 }
```

This gave me the URL

```
/assets?action=show&controller=user&id=1234
```

What should the link_to parameters be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to use named routes if possible (let Rails to the work for you).  That is, add a route to your routes file:

```
resources :users
```

You can then write your link_to method as:

```
link_to "User", user_path(@user)
```

or

```
link_to "User", user_path(1234)
```

Comment: and even just `@user` instead of `user_path(@user)`

Comment: The route was there, but I didn't realize I could use "user_path" and pass it an ID.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with `rake routes`, that can be a handy way to see what <named_route>_path and <named_route>_url methods are at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

For the HTML id

```
<%= link_to "User", {:controller => "user", :action => "show"}, :id => '1234' %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

For the path id

```
link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :id => @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/show/1">Profile</a>
```

Comment: This gives the same result, except that the id parameter is removed from the URL. I don't understand what you mean by path ID?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax albeit valid, harkens back to the Rails 2 days.

Why not use the built in url helpers? [URL Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)

This would allow you to pass the user in question as an object as the link_to

`<%= link_to "User", user_url( user_object ) %>`

or if you prefer to be explicit (this will add it as a params option though)

`<%= link_to "User", user_url( :id => '1234' ) %>`

Comment: My original attempt was directly from that page, albeit the "older more verbose, non-resource-oriented" version :) None of the other examples seemed to say anything about ID's though.

Comment: that way is fine and a better way to learn (IMO) because you'll be able to handle legacy code as you understand what the url helpers are simplifying. Anyway the helpers will setup what you pass to them as parameters on the url. I think (but haven't verified) that if the router recognizes the paramater it will properly set it up accoring to your routes, otherwise it tacks it onto the url as a _normal_ html param.